# Control who can run jobs on a specific slave

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've been trying to control the ability of running jobs on a specific node but unfortunately haven't found a plugin or a built in function for it.

Trying my luck here. 
I need to
* Control users who can configure jobs to run on a specific slave.
* No one else from admin group can execute jobs on this slave.

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to restrict users or jobs that can run on some node this plugin can assist you:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=69273423#content/view/69273423

Comment: No, i meant i want users not to be able to create/run jobs on a node

Comment: This is a great plugin, but unfortunately doesn't support pipelines. do you know of a similar plugin which has pipeline support?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [rubics answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47514614/8184374). Instead of "per branch" you can change the checks to be per slave.

Also have you tried using labels on your slaves? You can limit where jobs run based on slave label, and then also limit based on user in the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Jenkins – Implementing Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy plugin for the same.**

Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy is an authorization method using which we can define which user or group can do what actions on which job. This gives us a fine-grained control over user/group permissions per project.

Refer the following link for the documentation of project-based matrix authorization plugin installation and use.

[Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy plugin](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/jenkins-implementing-project-based-matrix-authorization-strategy/)

Comment: It doesn't give me the ability to restrict users from configuring jobs to runon a specific slave...